# Retrieve a list of values from a lookup table using db_select

Tags: database

I have a "jobs" table where each job can have multiple specialties. So I have a specialties table with a list of all available specialties and I have a lookup table that just has a job_number and a specialty_code in it so each job can be attached to multiple specialties. What I am trying to figure out is when I do a db_select, how can I have the job record print out once, but have a list of it's specialties print out also as part of that record? Here is what I have right now for my query:

```
$query = db_select("jobs", "j");
$query->fields('j');
$query->join('job_specialties', 'js', 'j.job_number = js.job_number');
$query->join('specialties', 's', 's.specialty_code = js.specialty_code');
$result = $query->distinct()->execute();
```

This gives me the correct records, but I want to display the list of specialties each job is attached to and that's where I'm not sure how to do that. Is there even a way using the database API to do that?

Essentially I would want to be able to display the records something like this. This is only one record, but you get the idea.

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Job Number</th>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Location</th>
      <th>Specialty</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td>12345</td>
    <td>Some Cool Job</td>
    <td>California</td>
    <td>SQL<br>HTML5<br>JavaScript</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add more fields to your query from the other tables that you have joined to:

```
$query->fields('js');
$query->fields('s');
```

Use hook_menu() to create your page if you want a custom one, then render it in PHP (I'm guessing at your result variable):

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
       ....
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th><?php>$result['job_number']<?></th>
      .....
 </table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I actually know how to add fields and display the data. The problem is right now if I add in $query->fields('s'); which will give me all of the fields in the specialties table then the jobs that are attached to multiple specialties get output multiple times in the result set. What I would like it to do is output the job ONCE and then have a delimited list of specialties that I can display for that job record. That's why I added distinct() into the query because the jobs were showing up multiple times for those attached to multiple specialties.

Comment: I did however add $query->fields('s'); which then spits out all of the specialty fields along with the job record as expected, but like I said multiple job records come back with the same job id. I just wanted to see if there was a way to have it return ONE job record with a "list" of specialties in a "specialties" field so I can display that on the front end for each job.

Comment: Sounds like you need multiple queries, one for the job info, then another to gather all of the specialties using the job id as a parameter, rather than joining the tables.  You *can* get SQL to return such things using sub-queries and the like, but it's easier to just grab the info and then manipulate it in PHP.